# C# Telegram.Bot удаление сообщения

Tags: c#

Привет всем короче проблема.
В библиотеке telegram.bot есть метод DeleteMessageAsync который удаляет сообщение,
И мне нужно удалить сообщение которое отправил мой бот, в интернете я нашел только как удалить сообщение которые отправил пользователь.
Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: И в чем конкретно у вас возникли трудности? При отправке сообщения, вам возвращается объект `Message`, у которого есть все необходимое для будущего удаления сообщения. Если нужны **все** сообщения удалить, то значит берите все сообщения канала или что там у вас и от туда забирайте те, которые отправил бот.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ так я вот и не понимаю как удалить те сообщения который отправил бот(как их взять)

Comment: Я вам выше сказал как, вы это пробовали? Задача ведь вполне логически решается, нету тут чего либо сверхестественного.

Comment: Хм, поизучал вопрос более детальней, ну и похоже на то, что в библиотеке попросту нету методов для получения **всех** сообщений, хотя официально, есть [API метод](https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.getMessages) для этого. Поищите, может я не прав (не нашел в исходниках этого метода), если нет, то вариантов у вас несколько: 1. Записывать после отрпавки сообщения к себе, в некий список. 2. Реализовать этот метод самостоятельно (благо библиотека открыта). 3. Искать альтернативы.

Answer (score 1):

Ну я удаляю сообщения присланные ботом по такой схеме:

1. Message message = update.Message; //присланное человеком сообщение
2. `await bot.DeleteMessageAsync( chatId: message.Chat.Id, messageId: message.MessageId-1,  cancellationToken: cancellationToken                                             );`

3)Готово, удалилось последнее отправленное ботом сообщение